# "Труба дело"

Tags: фразеология

Интересно было бы узнать этимологию поговорки "труба дело" или "дело труба". Почему - труба?

Answer (score 1):

"Дело труба" в эпоху дотрубной экономики образовалось из "вылететь в трубу" - обанкротиться, прогореть, пустить все дымом